# tfs gradle sonarcube analysis endpoint can't use token

Tags: gradle, tfs, sonarqube

On TFS 2017 R3 I configured a Gradle task. in the Gradle task, I checked "Run SonarQube analysis" and filled in the values.

My SonarQube endpoint (used for the prepare task) wasn't visible, so I created a generic endpoint.

The generic endpoint isn't taking my token, so I had to configure it with username/password.
Is there a way to change this?

I have looked around the internet for quite a while, but haven't found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/labs/sonarqube/?view=vsts).

> User name **This could be anything - it won't be used for SonarQube since the token is sufficient**
>
> Password/Token Key The default password for admin user in SonarQube